# Disabled inputs B&C if not inputA

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/6Pu3E/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var block = false;
    if $('#password').attr('disabled'); {
        block = false;
    }else{
        block = true;
    };
    if block {
        $('.form_input input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }else{
        $('.form_input input').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="password" value="" />
    <input class="form_input" id="Special" />
    <input class="form_input" id="Nothing Special" />
</form>
```

The goal is that all the inputs with a certain class get the attribute disabled if the first input with ID="password" does NOT have the attribute disabled. If the first input is disabled, nothing happens. I.e. the other inputs won't get the disabled attribute.

Comment: Your selector is wrong: `$('.form_input input')` selects input elements that are children of other elements with the class-name of `form_input`. As the input elements *have* that class-name, and `input` elements *can't have child-elements*, you should be using: `$('input.form_input')` instead. Oh, and as far as I know an `id` can't have white-space within it. So your second `.form_input` should have the `id` of `NothingSpecial` (or similar white-space-avoiding name).

Comment: You're right. I was typing too fast and both were actually supposed to be 'value' since I'm not using the ids anywhere.

Comment: That was a complete fail on my part. I know that about the child elements and I don't know what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Pu3E/18/)**

```
var block = false;
if ($('#password').attr('disabled')) {
    block = false;
} else {
    block = true;
}
if (block) {
    $('.form_input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
    $('.form_input').removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

​Or the ultra-condensed version:

```
$('.form_input').attr('disabled',!$('#password').attr('disabled') );​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Pu3E/23/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript syntax and use of `$()` are both incorrect. If statements require parentheses around the expression being evaluated, and `$('.form_input input')` looks for `<input>` elements within `.form_input` elements.

You can also shorten the entire block down to one line with the logic that you want the `disabled` property on `.form_input` elements to be the opposite of the `disabled` property of the `#password` element.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form_input').prop('disabled',!$('#password').prop('disabled'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = $('#password').attr('disabled');
    if (foo == 'disabled'){
    $('.form_input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }else{
    $('.form_input').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
});
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/thewingser/6Pu3E/27/

The use of the boolean `block` wasn't needed. to be honest my variable `foo` is not really needed. I just did it for readability.

Comment: element attributes that are dynamic (i.e. they change as a result of user interaction or other actions) are better accessed and altered through `.prop()`, which has the benefit of returning *truthy* values for properties like `disabled` and `checked`, as opposed to strings like 'disabled'

Comment: Oh okay, is it used much like `.attr()`?

Comment: Yes, it's used the same way, but rather than editing the serializable HTML attribute, it edits the actual DOM property. A minor difference in most scenarios, but important in others. See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/